# Simple Angular Module not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, module

So I'm trying to do a small test app with angular js I have

`<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
  </div>`

in the the body and this

```
<script>
      var testapp = angular.module("testApp",[]);
      testapp.controller("myCtrl",function ($scope) {
          $scope.firstName = "John";
          $scope.lastName = "Doe";
      });
  </script>
```

is what it's going off of. However, I'm still receiving this:

[image]

How can I get it to display what I want which is "John Doe"? I know I'm probably doing something simple wrong...

Comment: Any errors in the console? Maybe Angular isn't loaded.

Comment: @FrankModica yes: Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=myCtrl
    at angular.min.js:6
    at angular.min.js:93
    at ba (angular.min.js:76)
    at n (angular.min.js:68)
    at g (angular.min.js:61)
    at g (angular.min.js:62)
    at g (angular.min.js:62)
    at angular.min.js:61
    at angular.min.js:22
    at m.$eval (angular.min.js:148)
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:123

Comment: Quick correction to my code that doesn't solve it but testapp and testApp were named different, I've since fixed that. Still results in the same however.

Comment: Can you post your code in Plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine in the code snippet editor. 
Could you please post more details

Please find below the working example

```js
var testapp = angular.module("testApp",[]);
      testapp.controller("myCtrl",function ($scope) {
          $scope.firstName = "John";
          $scope.lastName = "Doe";
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you have any error in the console. Also please check whether angular is loaded

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create a seperate js file named module.js in which add your code as below
var testapp = angular.module("testApp",[]);
  testapp.controller("myCtrl",function ($scope) {
      $scope.firstName = "John";
      $scope.lastName = "Doe";
  });

//then inject module.js file below the angular.min.js and please make 
//angular.min.js locally because it won't work when you will offline
```

Comment: Hope this plunker can give you idea http://plnkr.co/edit/UkXKjmPFAWwoFGfC7WQs?p=info